# Eigenvalues of $A^\ast A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

How can I show that if $A$ is unitarily diagonalisable,  then an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $A^*A$ and eigenvalue of $A^*A = |\lambda|^2$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

And for the eigenvectors, the eigenvectors of a diagonal matrix are $(1,0,\cdots ,0)^T$, $(0,1,0,\cdots ,0)^T$ , ... $(0,\cdots ,0,1)^T$

And since $A$ and $A^*A$ are similar to a diagonal matrix using the same diagonalizing transformation (as Jan explained), thus they have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: As I understand your argumentation, it says that any two diagnosable matrices have the same eigenvectors, which isn't true. The point is that $ A $ and $ AA^{*} $ are similar to a diagonal matrix using the same diagonalizing transformation.